# Count of business days between several date columns in Snowflake PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

This is a very popular topic on SO, from what my searches have turned up -- but I will explain why other answers are not working for me.

I am using PostgreSQL on Snowflake. My data table, t1, looks something like:

```
client category order_date  invoice_date date_fulfilled date_shipped
ACME   A        2023-08-01  2023-08-01   2023-08-03     2023-09-20
ACME   B        2023-06-26  2023-06-26   2023-07-03     2023-08-03
ACME   C        2023-07-14  2023-07-17   2023-07-28     2023-08-28
```

What I need is to calculate the three gaps between the date columns, *excluding holidays and weekends.* So, by just looking at the calendar and counting, my output should look something like

```
Client Category order_to_invoice  invoice_to_fill fill_to_ship
ACME   A        0                 2               32
ACME   B        0                 5               22
ACME   C        1                 9               21
```

Let's further say that I have a list of the weekends and holidays I want to omit. I had to create it myself using this code:

```
with dates_to_omit (omit_date) as (select * from values
(date '2023-07-01'),
(date '2023-07-02'),
(date '2023-07-04'),
(date '2023-07-08'),
(date '2023-07-09'),
(date '2023-07-15'),
(date '2023-07-16'),
(date '2023-07-22'),
(date '2023-07-23'),
(date '2023-07-29'),
(date '2023-07-30'),
(date '2023-08-05'), 
(date '2023-08-06'),
(date '2023-08-12'),
(date '2023-08-13'),
(date '2023-08-19'),
(date '2023-08-20'),
(date '2023-08-26'),
(date '2023-08-27'),
(date '2023-09-02'),
(date '2023-09-03'), 
(date '2023-09-04'),
(date '2023-09-09'),
(date '2023-09-10'),
(date '2023-09-16'),
(date '2023-09-17')
)
```

The problem is that all of the Stack Overflow answers I find on this, though they work when applied to arbitrary date numbers, seem to fall apart when applied to a table. For example, I found an answer which suggested...

```
SELECT
count(s) FILTER (WHERE (EXTRACT(isodow FROM s::date) NOT IN (6, 7))
  AND s::date NOT IN ('2022-05-05', '2022-05-11', '2022-05-27'))
FROM generate_series('2022-05-01'::date, '2022-05-31'::date, interval '1 day') g (s);
```

...which works great for those specific date numbers in the code. But when I tried to apply that to my table (note that "extract(isodow)" was changed to "extract(dow)" because Snowflake did not recognize "isodow")...

```
select t1.client, t1.category,
count(s) FILTER (WHERE (extract(dow from s::date) NOT IN (6, 7))
  AND s::date NOT IN (select omit_date from dates_to_omit))
FROM generate_series(t1.order_date, t1.invoice_date, interval '1 day') g (s)
```

...I got an error saying that the WHERE statement following the FILTER statement was not valid. What can I try next?

Comment: Hi - you can’t be using  Postgresql on Snowflake as they are two entirely separate DBMSs - that makes no more sense than saying you are using Oracle on SQL Server . Please update your question with the actual DBMS you are using

Comment: @NickW I don't know what to tell you. Our database is PostgreSQL and the vendor we use to design dashboards for it is Snowflake.

Comment: I guess you may be working with a company called Snowflake to design your dashboards but the tag you are using, snowflake-cloud-database-platform, is specific to the Snowflake DBMS hence your tags are incompatible/confusing